# PHP Form not Submitting Properly in FireFox 26.0

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form on my page and when it is submit it gets sent to a php page to email me the for m inputs. The form works correctly on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m and IE10, but on Firefox 26.0 it displays the following on the PHP page after the user sends the form:

```
Thank you, $fname! we will get back to you.

"; print"

Today's date is $date.
"; $to = "myemail@email.com"; $subject = "Financing for $fname $lname"; $body = " Date: $date \n\n Note: If any fields have been left blank it means the user did not input anything. \n\n First name: $fname \n Last name: $lname \n Company: $cname \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Fax: $fax \n Address: $address \n City: $city \n Province: $province \n Postal Code: $postal \n Equipment Type: $et \n Amount: $amount\n\n"; $headers = "From: info@gbmtrailer.ca"; mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); ?>
```

Here is the PHP that is displayed on a Chrome web page:

```
Thank you, ! we will get back to you.

Today's date is Feb 12 2014.
```

Here is my PHP code for the PHP page:

```
 <?php 

$fname= $_POST['fname'];
$lname= $_POST['lname'];
$cname= $_POST['cname'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$fax= $_POST['fax'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$city= $_POST['city'];
$province= $_POST['province'];
$postal= $_POST['postal'];
$et= $_POST['et'];
$amount= $_POST['amount'];

$date = gmdate("M d Y");

print"<p>Thank you, $fname! we will get back to you.</p>";
print"<p>Today's date is $date.</p>";

$to = "------";
$subject = "Financing for $fname $lname";
$body = " Date: $date \n\n Note: If any fields have been left blank it means the user did not input anything. \n\n First name: $fname \n Last name: $lname \n Company: $cname \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Fax: $fax \n Address: $address \n City: $city \n Province: $province \n Postal Code: $postal \n Equipment Type: $et \n Amount: $amount\n\n";
$headers = "From: info@gbmtrailer.ca";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
?>
```

Here is the form code on the index.html page:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta name="author" content="Kelsey Nealon(Kelseynealon@gmail.com), Contract Web Developer" />
<meta name="description" content="GBM Trailer Service Ltd. Calgary-based, proudly serving the tanker and bulk goods transportation industry for over 25 years." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Tanker, Barrel, Parts, Betts, Camloc, Scully, Lubecore, Dixon, GBM, Flotech" />
<title>GBM Trailer Service Ltd. ::: Financing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/mobilemenu.css"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery.custom-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.custom-scrollbar.js"></script>
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".nav-button").click(function () {
            $(".nav-button,.primary-nav").toggleClass("open");
            });    
        });
    </script>

<script src="respond.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["lname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Last name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Phone number must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["city"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("City/Town must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;    
 if(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value.match(mailformat))
{   
}  
else  
{  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address");  
document.myForm.email.focus(); 
return false;  
}  

  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;  
  if(document.forms["myForm"]["phone"].value.match(phoneno))  
  {   
  }  
  else  
  {  
     alert("Not a valid Phone Number");  
     return false;  
  }  

}

function ValidateEmail(inputText)   
{  
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;    
 if(inputText.value.match(mailformat))
{  
document.myForm.email.focus();  
}  
else  
{  
alert("You have entered an invalid email address");  
document.myForm.email.focus(); 
return false;  
}  
}  
</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-45342007-3', 'gbmtrailer.ca');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#102540">
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <div id="div1" class="fluid">

<div id="wrapper2"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/bannerpics.jpg" alt="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo" title="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo" id="logo"/></a></div>
  <div id="wrapper3"><button class="nav-button">Toggle Navigation</button></div>

<div id="navcontain">
            <ul class="primary-nav">
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../completions/index.html">Completions</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../insuranceclaims/index.html">Insurance Claims</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../sales/index.html">Sales</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../service/index.html">Service</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../truckmounts/index.html">Truck Mounts</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../certificationsandinspections/index.html">Certifications & Inspections</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../contactus/index.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="../parts/index.html">Parts</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="../repairsandmaintenance/index.html">Repairs & Maintenance</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="../warranty/index.html">Warranty</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="../careers/index.html">Careers</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Parts Catalogue</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="../modifications/index.html">Modifications</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="../steambays/index.html">Steam Bays</a>
                </li>
                 <li><a href="../financing/index.html">Financing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
  <img src="images/desktopgreybackground2.jpg" id="background4">
  <img src="images/desktopgreybackground.jpg" id="background3">
  <img id="background2" src="images/background6.jpg"/>
  <div id="cover"></div>

  <div id="mainnavdesktop">
      <a href="../index.html"><img id="logo2" src="images/gbmlogo.jpg" alt="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo" title="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Logo"/></a>
        <a href="../sales/index.html"><img src="images/sales.jpg" alt="sales" title="Sales" id="sales"></a><a href="../completions/index.html"><img src="images/completions.jpg" alt="completions" title="Completions" id="completions"/></a><a href="../insuranceclaims/index.html"><img src="images/insuranceclaims.jpg" alt="insurance claims" title="Insurance Claims" id="insuranceclaims"/></a><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/home.jpg" alt="home" title="Home" id="home"/></a>
        <a href="../service/index.html"><img src="images/service.jpg" alt="service" title="Service" id="service"/></a><a href="../truckmounts/index.html"><img src="images/truckmounts.jpg" alt="truck mounts" title="Truck Mounts" id="truckmounts"/></a><a href="../certificationsandinspections/index.html"><img src="images/certificationsandinspections.jpg" alt="certifications and inspections" title="Certifications and Inspections" id="certificationsandinspections"/></a><a href="../contactus/index.html"><img src="images/contactus.jpg" alt="contact us" title="Contact Us" id="contactus"/></a>
        <a href="../parts/index.html"><img src="images/parts.jpg" alt="parts" title="Parts" id="parts"/></a><a href="../repairsandmaintenance/index.html"><img src="images/repairsandmaintenance.jpg" alt="repairs and maintenance" title="Repairs and Maintenance" id="repairsandmaintenance"/></a><a href="../warranty/index.html"><img src="images/warranty.jpg" alt="warranty" title="Warranty" id="warranty"/></a><a href="../careers/index.html"><img src="images/careers.jpg" alt="careers" title="Careers" id="careers"/></a>
        <img src="images/partscatalogue.jpg" alt="parts catalogue" title="Parts Catalogue" id="partscatalogue"/><a href="../modifications/index.html"><img src="images/modifications.jpg" alt="modifications" title="Modifications" id="modifications"/></a><a href="../steambays/index.html"><img src="images/steambays.jpg" alt="steam bays" title="Steam Bays" id="steambays"/></a><a href="../financing/index.html"><img src="images/financing.jpg" alt="financing" title="Financing" id="financing"/></a>
  </div>

<img src="images/gbmtrailerservice_trailer.png" alt="G.B.M. Trailer Service LTD. Trailer Graphic" id="trailer23">

<div id="description">
  <h1><strong>G.B.M. FINANCIAL</strong></h1>
  <p class="box1" style="text-align:left;">Offering a full variety of financial services for all heavy equipment purchases whether you found it at G.B.M. or somewhere else. We will guide you through the application and approval process.</p><p class="box2">Offering a full variety of financial services for all heavy equipment purchases whether you found it at G.B.M. or somewhere else. We will guide you through the application and approval process.</p><img src="images/heidisawatzkygbm.png" alt="Heidi Sawatzky" title="Controller" id="heidi"><img src="images/robdewargbm.png" alt="Rob Dewar" title="General Manager" id="rob"><p id="heidiemail" style="text-align:center;">Heidi Sawatzky<br /><a href="mailto:hsawatzky@gbmtrailer.ca?subject=Web%20Finance%20Information">hsawatzky@gbmtrailer.ca</a></p><p id="robemail" style="text-align:center">Rob Dewar<br /><a href="mailto:rob.dewar@gbmtrailer.ca?subject=Web%20Finance%20Information">rob.dewar@gbmtrailer.ca</a>
  <br />
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p class="box3" style="text-align:left;">Heidi or Rob will help you secure your purchase. They will ensure that you are looked after and that you are suited with the right financial package. Contact them by phone 403 279 9717 or by email with any questions you may have.</p>
</div>

<div id="contenttext">
<form name="myForm" action="financing.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post"><H2 style="text-align:center;" id="conhead">Contact Information</h2><br /><br />
<p>  
First name * <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="fname"><br /><br />
Last name * <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="lname"><br /><br />
Company <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="cname"><br /><br />
Email * <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="email"><br /><br />
Phone * <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="phone"><br /><br />
Fax <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="fax"><br /><br />
Address <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="address"><br /><br />
City / Town * <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="city"><br /><br />
Province <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="province"><br /><br />
Postal Code <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="postal"><br /><br />
Equipment Type <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="et"><br /><br />
Amount <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="amount"><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="submitbutton"></p></form>
<p class="ppolicy"><strong>Privacy Policy:</strong> All information gathered in this form will be kept strictly confidential.</p><p class="required">
*Required</p><p id="tools">TOOLS: <a style="color:white;" href="loancalculator.html">LOAN CALCULATOR</a>, <a style="color:white;" href="creditapplication.docx" title="Basic credit application word document" target="_blank">CREDIT APPLICATION</a></p><p id="tools1"><br />TOOLS: <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><a style="color:white;" href="loancalculator.html" title="Loan Calculator">LOAN CALCULATOR</a><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <a style="color:white;" href="creditapplication.docx" title="Basic credit application word document" target="_blank">CREDIT APPLICATION</a></p>
</div>
<div id="bottomquote">
  Your Certified Tanker Trailer Specialist
</div>
<div id="bottomcontactinfo">
  <em>Phone <a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:1-4032799717">403 279 9717</a> or <a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="tel:1-888-426-9717">1 888 426 9717</a> 9300 Endeavor Dr. SE, Calgary Alberta, T3S 0A1<br /><a style="color:white; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:info@gbmtrailer.ca">info@gbmtrailer.ca</a>
</div>

<img src="images/visamastercardlogos.gif" id="visamastercardlogos" alt="Visa and Mastercard Logo" title="Visa and Mastercard Logo">

<a href="#"><img id="mycart" src="images/mycart.gif" alt="My Cart" title="My Cart"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin()
{
myWindow = window.open("","", "width=300,height=500");
}
</script>
<script>
<!--
var autoSizeText;
autoSizeText = function() {
  var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
  elements = $('.resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    el = elements[_i];
    _results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, _results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elNewFontSize;
        elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
      };
      _results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        _results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return _results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return _results;
};

autoSizeText(); // here is where we call the function.
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please give me any suggestions. All help will be appreciated.

Comment: So it's printing your PHP code?

Comment: PHP only runs on server side, the browser should not influence it , what is the client side part of the code?

Comment: Are you sure you have a `.php` file?

Comment: I edited my question to show what it displays on Chrome and what it displays on FireFox. Yes, it's printing the code on Firefox, but not on Chrome or IE.

Comment: @FabioCosta what do you mean by client side? The HTML form page or the full php page? MahanGM, yes, it is a .php file.

Comment: can u do a hard refresh of the browser and then try ?

Comment: Client side would be the form that sends it.

Comment: This has got to be a caching issue... try clearing your firefox and chrome cache and trying it again

Comment: When I run it in FireFox (v26), I get this: 

`Thank you, Rick! we will get back to you.

Today's date is Feb 12 2014.`

Comment: paste your client side code. There is no reason y it should work on one browsers and not work on the other. cos it is the same server that processes for both. except if you posting with a javascript code. Then possibly some code not working in chrome. Or Also try cacheing like they suggest

Comment: Just cleared the cache and it's doing the same thing. Pasting whole client side code.

Comment: post your javascript that could be were the error is. It is possibly not posting some values rite on that browser you complain of

Comment: Try it from FireFox on your phone or another PC just to see if you get the same results.

Comment: Browsers sometimes overlook some javascript errors while others would not. so pasted it so we review

Comment: Where is it getting the `Click here to return to the previous page.`?  I don't see that in your code.

Comment: it is likely to be in the javascript. he should paste that code

Comment: Also enable error_reporting so that php can show you all errors. There as to be some error in your variables

Comment: That is in my PHP file but it is outside of the PHP tags. The PHP code is actually inside of HTML code. My javascript is in my HTML page, but I don't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are posting with Javascript check your Javascript. Also clear cache on the browser that is not working. and restart that browser.